# DirectX 9, 10 Hooking to overlay content on a fullscreen game

Tags: c#, c++, directx, hook, overlay

I am looking to create content over a game much like xfire or fraps

I understand what they are doing full and well, and I hate asking for help, I like to be independent.

I have tried EVERYTHING to get some code working to where I can draw on top of a fullscreen game. I have tried it with C++, C#, with EasyHook...you name it.

all the source code examples I have used give me errors or break in Visual Studio 2010. ideally I want to program it in C# but I have also tried examples in C++, the biggest problem I have had with C++ programs is getting detours.h, and other required header files, I tried installing it, but that didn't work, couldn't find the detours.h file on my system to include it in my solution, and I couldn't find it online with the matching .lib...

needless to say this has been the most frustrating 10 hours of my life. I am at my breaking point and what I need is someone to step me through some code that works in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 x64. Once I get some code that allows me to draw on top of a fullscreen directX program, I can rip it apart and figure out how it ticks...thanks.

I would be eternally grateful to anyone who can step me through some code to get it to work, you have no idea.

Comment: Right after post this, I found this, http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=161045

trying it out now. This is the most detailed one I have found. If anyone still wants to help, by all means you can still help me :-D

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925981/overlaying-on-a-3d-fullscreen-application

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a sample code for directx 10 hooking.

http://www.codeforfun.it/2013/09/07/d3d10-proxy-dll-c/

Here you can find the code for directx 9 hooking, but with a proxy dll.

http://www.codeforfun.it/2012/08/30/directx-hooking-with-a-proxy-dll/