# How to make an overlay

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, direct3d, direct3d11

I'm wondering how I can create an overlay with Direct3D11 (C++).
(Like the xfire game chat that renders content over another program in fullscreen)

I know the basics of Direct3D11, but I have no idea how to make programs communicate with each other.
Or is that not necessary?

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925981/overlaying-on-a-3d-fullscreen-application