# python show tooltip window on click

Tags: python, user-interface, label, tooltip, autohotkey

There is command In the AutoHotKey that shows tooltip with some message on the top of the screen. I want to do it on python.

In more details I need to make an application, that will work in background, always tracking a keyboard. On the specific hotkey it should show on the top of the screen a message without grabbing focus from other application. And it should remove this message after some conditions (e.g. mouse moving). It should work with full screen apps too.

I couldn't find how to do it on python, or what libraries should I use. Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Global tooltips are created via WINAPI [CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx) with `TOOLTIPS_CLASS` for window class. There are [some examples](https://www.google.com/#q=python+%22CreateWindowEx%22) which you can adapt. See also [the Autohotkey implementation](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/093e04d033034399ff98c356ad3c0bb8cc074b67/source/script2.cpp#L718).

Shell tray tooltips are created via [Shell_NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx).
A working example: [wontoncc/balloontip.py](https://gist.github.com/wontoncc/1808234) and [the Autohotkey implementation](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/093e04d033034399ff98c356ad3c0bb8cc074b67/source/script2.cpp#L880).

Comment: Yes, I think tray tooltip is suitable for me. But there is problem: it doesnt work when other app is in full screen mod. I've tried do it with PyQt4, but got same result. Is it solvable?

Comment: @PG_LoLo, it's complicated. See [Overlaying on a 3D fullscreen application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/925981) or an AHK lib [GPF v1.1c - Overlaying Direct3D games (DX 8+9)](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/42069-lib-gpf-v11c-overlaying-direct3d-games-dx-89-fixed/). Or search another example.